# how to test methods which set private variables in viewcontroller unit testing?

Tags: ios, swift, tdd

I have a ViewController, which conforms to a protocol. ViewController has the following private UI components:
backgroundImage, logoimage,  loginButton , signupButton - all of these are private. (hence not accessible by unit tests)

How can I test the below protocol method implementation in unit testing? I am using `XCTestFramework` for unit testing.

```
extension ViewController : ViewControllerProtocol{
    func setbackgroundImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        backgroundImage.image = image
    }

    func setLogoImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        logoImage.image = image
    }

    func setLoginButtontitle(_ title: String) {
        loginButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }

    func setSignupButtonTitle(_ title: String) {
        signupButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }
}

protocol ViewControllerProtocol {
    func setbackgroundImage(_ image : UIImage)
    func setLogoImage(_ image : UIImage)
    func setLoginButtontitle(_ title: String)
    func setSignupButtonTitle(_ title: String)
    func setTitleLabel(_ title: String)
    func setContinuewithoutsignupTitle(_ title: String)
}
```

Comment: Have you used the [`XCTest Framework`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest)?

Comment: yes, i am using xctest framework

Comment: where is your `ViewControllerProtocol` defined? Can you share that code?

Comment: i have updated in question.

Comment: Are you asking for just a sample unit test?

Comment: no, i am asking, how can i test that private member have set values properly through unit tests. ?

Comment: The awkwardness of the question reveals a possible design issue. What function does this protocol serve? What are these properties used for? Testing that setters set isn't very interesting or useful by itself. I'd be more interested in testing the actual goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still unit test those values below by adding public getters

```swift
protocol ViewControllerProtocol {
    func setbackgroundImage(_ image : UIImage)
    func setLogoImage(_ image : UIImage)
    func setLoginButtontitle(_ title: String)
    func setSignupButtonTitle(_ title: String)
    func setTitleLabel(_ title: String)
    func setContinuewithoutsignupTitle(_ title: String)
    func getbackgroundImage() -> UIImage?
    func getlogoImage() -> UIImage?
    func getloginButtonTitle() -> String?
    func getsignupButtonTitle() -> String?
}

class MainTest: XCTestCase {

    let viewController = ViewController()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    func testExample() {
        guard let testImage1 = UIImage(named: "testImage1") else {
            XCTFail("Could not load test image 1")
            return
        }
        viewController.setbackgroundImage(testImage1)
        XCTAssert(viewController.getbackgroundImage() == testImage1)
        guard let testImage2 = UIImage(named: "testImage2") else {
            XCTFail("Could not load test image 2")
            return
        }
        viewController.setLogoImage(testImage2)
        XCTAssert(viewController.getlogoImage() == testImage2)
        viewController.setLoginButtontitle("test")
        XCTAssert(viewController.getloginButtonTitle() == "test")
        viewController.setSignupButtonTitle("test")
        XCTAssert(viewController.getsignupButtonTitle() == "test")
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, public getter should work fine. thanks a lot.